# Do copper water pipes split underground?

Tags: underground, copper-pipe

I'm trying to figure out where I may have a water leak. This is related to [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/239594/is-the-hissing-sound-of-water-the-source-point-of-the-leak?noredirect=1#comment464945_239594) question. I'm thinking capping and bypassing pipes is easy provide they do not split underground. Do/can they split underground? Ideally code would not allow it but I'm no plumber. Thanks.

Update:
I think I wasn't clear when I said "split". By "split" I mean have a T that will start another run going somewhere. I'm in S. California I don't get freezing here. Thanks.

Comment: copper pipes can develop pin holes anywhere.  code calls for a thicker copper pipe if used in concrete but all pipes have lifespans.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger Agreed! While it probably won't split unless it froze and thawed, pin hole failures are not uncommon. I can't think of why someone would run copper underground.   It's expensive, hard to work with compared to PVC or HDPE , PEX, Polyethylene.  Depending on soil conditions (esp. acidity) copper could fail fairly quickly

Comment: Looking at update ; There my be "T" and other fittings in buried pipe. But from what I have seen it would not be common in water supply pipe for a home.  Sewer pipe will normally have branches .